# How can I convert a char to a double from 0-1?

Tags: java, char, type-conversion, double

I'm trying to convert an array of chars to an array of doubles with each one between 0-1, so that `a` would be `0` and `z` would be `1`. Currently, I've thought of this method,

```java
public static double[] charToDouble(char[] chars){
  double[] doubles=new double[chars.length];
  double one=1;
  double twentySix=26;
  double eachChar=one/twentySix;
  for(int i=0; i<chars.length; i++){
    int charNum=((int)input)-96;
    doubles[i]=eachChar*charNum;
  }
  return doubles;
}
```

but `a` would be converted to `1/26` instead of `0`.

Comment: `1/26` is integer division

Comment: gblodgett thanks, I'll edit the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to divide by `25`, not `26`, because there are 25 *intervals* between 26 *letters*.

You are over-thinking your approach; you only need 1 line of code in a simple loop: simply subtract `a` from the `char` of each letter and divide the result by `25`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    doubles[i] = (chars[i] - 'a') / 25d;
}
```

Note the little “d” after 25 - that makes the 25 a `double`, which makes the result a `double`. If you don’t do that, you get integer arithmetic, which will make every letter except `z` produce `0`.

Comment: `25 == 'z' - 'a'`  (but not double) -  (BTW backticks are wrong)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger backticks were from iPhone keyboard (fixed now), but thanks for pointing it out. The arithmetic is correct however: as long as at least one of the operands is a `double`, the calculation and result are also `double`.

Comment: I just mean we can (should?) use  `'z'-'a'` instead of 25 (like using `'a'` instead of 96)